# snakemake: Problem with --rerun-triggers flag and bash variable

Tags: bash, snakemake

I have a problem when I try to provide the --rerun-triggers flag as a bash variable.

My command is

```
snakemake $snakemake_extra -pr --snakefile Snakefile --configfile config.yaml -c 20 -n
```

and snakemake_extra is a bash variable defined as

```
snakemake_extra="--rerun-triggers {mtime,input,params}"
```

I get the following error:

> snakemake: error: argument --rerun-triggers: invalid choice: '{mtime,input,params}' (choose from 'mtime', 'params', 'input', 'software-env', 'code')

The problem seems to be that snakemake(?) adds single-quotes before and after the `{}`.

When I insert the --rerun-triggers flag directly (without bash variable) it works fine. I need the bash variable however and can also not use a snakemake profile yaml.

Is there any possible workaround?

I am using snakemake version 7.12.1.

Thanx,
Carlus

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but if it helps, `"--rerun-triggers mtime input params"` (space-separated list, no braces) should work in the same way and it's more readable.

Comment: In fact, I'm surprised that the argument parser doesn't complain with `--rerun-triggers {mtime,input,params}`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possible workaround?

https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Use array.

```
snakemake_extra=( --rerun-triggers {mtime,input,params} )
... "${snakemake_extra[@]}" ...
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, I still get the same error

Comment: `When I insert the --rerun-triggers flag directly` How do you "insert the flag directory" _exactly_? Are you typing in terminal exactly `--rerun-triggers "{mtime,input,params}"`? `invalid choice: '{mtime,input,params}'` that's what is says, it's an invalid choice. I do not know what choice do you want to make...

Comment: Inserting directly means here
`snakemake --rerun-triggers {mtime,input,params} ...`

Comment: Then it differs with quotes. Note that `{mtime,input,params}` is the same as `mtime input params` in interactive bash input with brace expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Bash expands the braces when you provide them on the command line without embedding them in a variable, but it won't otherwise (see, for example, [Brace expansion from a variable in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30064674/610375)).
A fix is to expand your variable before using it:

```bash
snakemake_extra="--rerun-triggers mtime input params"
```